# Can not load model in controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I am working in **CakePHP version 1.3.6.** I have created controller for api in my project.

Here, I have load created one model as DealPurchase.php and in this model I have write some code like,

```
<?php 
  class DealPurchase extends AppModel {
      public $actsAs = array('Containable');
      public $belongsTo = array('User');
  }
?>
```

Now, In my controller(android_controller.php) i have write my function as :

```
function get_all_deal()
{
    $this->layout = "";        
    $this->loadModel('DealPurchase');
    $condition2 = "DealPurchase.deal_status= '0' AND DealPurchase.user_id = '45'";
    $all_merchant = $this->DealPurchase->find('all',array('conditions'=>$condition2));
}
```

When I call this function my page display as blank because of some error.So what is problem in my code?

Comment: please show which error you got . and which line error occurs .you can debug($all_merchant); to find error.

Comment: Make sure debug level is 2.  Then let us know what "some error" is.

Comment: It gives nothing. But It solved In another function there is a syntex error thats why its not working.

Answer (score -1):

You should try debugging here. Please be sure that debugging is enabled in your config.

```
$this->loadModel('DealPurchase');

$condition2 = array(
   "DealPurchase.deal_statue=0", 
   "DealPurchase.user_id = 45"
);

$all_merchant = $this->DealPurchase->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => $condition2
));

debug($all_merchant);       // See what's being printed.
exit;
```

On a side note, I'd suggest you to upgrade to at least CakePHP 2, now that version 3 has been running for about a year.